# Is it more, or less, secure to use a different $F$ and $G$ for a Lamport signature?

Tags: hash-signature, one-time-signature

A [Lamport signature](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2016/12/Constructing-Digital-Signatures-from-a-One-Way-Function.pdf) is made as follows:

1. Alice stores $k_1, \cdots, k_{n'} \leftarrow K $ as her "private key", with one-way function $F: K\to V$, $n'>n$, and (easily enough) all $F(k_i)\neq F(k_j)$.
2. Alice publishes $F$, $G$, and $\alpha = \left(F(k_1), \cdots, F(k_{n'})\right)$ as her "public key", with one-way function $G:M\to \binom{\{1, \cdots, n'\}}{n}$ <sup>[[notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/905955/188128)]</sup>.
3. Alice later publishes $\sigma_\alpha(m)=(k_{i_1}, \cdots, k_{i_n})$ as her "signature" on $m$, with $(i_1, \cdots, i_n) = G(m)$.

   - Alice then destroys all stored $k_i|i\notin G(m)$ to prevent any subsequent $\sigma_\alpha(m')$ from being created, which would leak additional values of $k_i$ and [rapidly destroy](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2640/8287) the scheme's security.
4. To verify $\sigma_\alpha(m)$, Bob simply checks that $F(\sigma_\alpha(m)_j)=\alpha_i$ forall $i\in G(m)$ and $G(m)_j=i$.

Now, Wikipedia provides a [reference implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport_signature):

- $n=256$, $n'=2n$
  (the original paper only bothered specifying $n=20$ and $n'=2n$, to allow an apples-to-apples comparison with [Rabin's](http://publications.csail.mit.edu/lcs/pubs/pdf/MIT-LCS-TR-212.pdf) scheme which Lamport intended to obsolete by his own.)
- $F=\phi=\text{SHA}_n: \{0,1\}^*\to\{0,1\}^n$
  (the original paper did not even bother specifying any $K$, $V$, or $\phi$.)
- $G(m)=R\circ\phi(m)=(1 + \phi(m)_1, \cdots, 2n - 1 + \phi(m)_n)$
  (Wikipedia's construction of $R$, despite not being surjective and effectively constraining $n':=2n$, is nevertheless a clear improvement over the original paper's construction, which was a partial function thus might, “undesirabl[y]”, require the sender to brute-force a valid value via a nonce on $m$.)

Clearly, in this instance, $F$ and $G$ are "pretty much the same function"; each is a "thin wrapper" around $\phi$, i.e. with a trivial left-inverse.

So I'm wondering: does it harm, or help, the security of this scheme to have $F$ and $G$ be "the same function" like this? (And is it any particular risk for $G$ not to be surjective?)

Dr. Lamport seems to have mostly proposed similar constructions to Wikipedia's in his paper and raised no similar concerns on them, so I assume this is *probably* OK, but I don't know what all (if anything) modern cryptography or cryptanalysis has to say about either point.

---

The reason I'm asking is: I'm writing a reference software implementation that includes PKCS#8 serialization and deserialization, and I'm wondering if I should create separate parameters for $F$ and $G$ or have them "hard-coded" to be the same (and/or if I should hard-code in the behavior of $R$ despite the lack of a trivially correct choice for it).

Comment: In particular: it would seem that skimping on $F$ saves a lot of space and resources compared to skimping on $G$ for minimal weakening of the scheme; is this intuition off-base?

Comment: (As for the non-surjectivity of Wikipedia's construction of $R$ vs the partiality of Lamport's preliminary construction: [you gotta pick one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2338488/188128), so WP's approach is probably the most correct.)